# What is the nuance of (noun)+願います?

Tags: grammar

My boss *(early 60s, former department chief, male, Tokai Region)* often uses "(noun)+願います" in written requests like this:

> 翻訳願います
> ご確認願います.

I haven't come across it before and can't find info online due to the overly similar standard "お願いします".
I understand what it means, but what is the nuance? Is this old man speech, boss to 部下 speech, is this regional, or standard? etc. Is it identical in meaning to お願いします or is it stiffer, more like an order, etc?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

～願います is not regional nor old. Basically it's a little less polite version of お願いします. It's okay in a mail from a boss, but it's generally safe to avoid using this when you write something to your boss or your business partner. It also depends on how much you are asking for; メールをご確認願います and ご遠慮願います tend to sound safe, but you should avoid 願います when you make some major request politely.